# Can i use PPPoE with any router

Tags: router, modem, pppoe

I have currently [this router](http://www.tp-link.com/products/productDetails.asp?class=&content=spe&pmodel=TD-8810)

As the modem has only one ethernet port , i have one connection coming from modem to my computer Ethernet card.

Now when i restart my computer i have one connection made on my desktop whose setting says somethig like

PPPoE

when i double click on that it dials connection and then on bottom right hand side i gets two computer icons showing that my internet is connected and i can surf the internet..

now i want to ask that why i need  make the PPPoE connection from desktop computer.

Shouldn't modem should do this automatically and when i restart my computer i get the internet straight way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the specifications, your router supports PPPoE. If you have access to the web interface, you can configure it as PPPoE client (now it's probably configured as transparent bridge). You'll have to configure it's LAN interface with a private ip and then configure your computer ethernet card accordingly (maybe just activate the DHCP server on the router). Take care to abilitate NAT on the router, too!